# How to improve this SQL query (SQLite and PHP)

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I am rendering an array based on data from multiple db tables in SQLite.

Tables:

- staff - Contains all users/staff members that can have certificates
- certificates --- Contains all available certificates that a user can have
- rel__staff_certificate --- Contains certificates connected (relation) to a user

TABLE `staff`

```
`staff_id`  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
```

TABLE `certificates`

```
`cert_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`caption`   TEXT NOT NULL,
`description`   TEXT
```

TABLE `rel__staff_certificate`

```
`rel_id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`staff_id`  INTEGER,
`cert_id`   INTEGER,
`cert_date` TEXT NOT NULL,
`comments`  TEXT
```

.

.

So here is the deal:

```
// Get all available certificates
$sql_get_cert = "SELECT * FROM certificates ORDER BY cert_id ASC";

// Get all certificates for staff user
$sql_get_staff_cert_rel = "SELECT * FROM rel__staff_certificate WHERE staff_id = :staff_id AND cert_id = :cert_id LIMIT 1";

// Prepare SQL queries...
$get_cert_rel = $PDODB->prepare($sql_get_staff_cert_rel);
$get_cert = $PDODB->prepare($sql_get_cert);

// Get all certificates to array $certdata
$get_cert->execute();
$certdata = $get_cert->fetchAll();

// Create the array where I want to push data to:
$staffdata[$i] = array(
    $staff['staff_id'], // $staff() is populated earlier and works just fine
    $staff['name'],
    $ccdata['region'],  // $ccdata() is populated earlier and works just fine
    $ccdata['cc_code']
);

// Loop through all available certificates in table ´certificates´
foreach ($certdata as $cert) {
    // Bind values for the relation SQL now when we have them all
    $get_cert_rel->bindValue(':staff_id', $staff['staff_id']);
    $get_cert_rel->bindValue(':cert_id', $cert['cert_id']);
    $get_cert_rel->execute();

    // Get the certification relation data to array $certreldata()
    $certreldata = $get_cert_rel->fetch();

    // If a certificate date exists, then use that for our array which tells us that this staff has this certificate and was certified on this date
    if (!empty($certreldata['cert_date'])) { 
        array_push($staffdata[$i], $certreldata['cert_date']);
    }
    // If no certificate date exsits, then just add value "N/A" as not available
    else {
        array_push($staffdata[$i], 'N/A');
    }
}
```

OK so thats it! It works, but as you can see I am doing a lot of SQL execution to the SQL server in the foreach() loop and I do not believe this is very good as it will consume a lot of unnecessary time.

Can anyone tell me how to do this with a single SQL query instead? Or tell me how to improve the code to speed things up further in other ways?

Thank you.

Comment: How about using JOINS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` for such queries.

Using a `LEFT JOIN` You join the two tables using the private key of first table (left) and a foreign key of the second (right) while if there is no row found in the second (right) table, the columns for the right table will be filled with `NULL` values:

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM certificates AS c
LEFT JOIN rel__staff_certificate AS sc ON sc.cert_id = c.cert_id
WHERE sc.staff_id = ?
ORDER BY c.cert_id
```

USING an `INNER JOIN` You join two tables the same way as in `LEFT JOIN` but if there is no entry for the private key of left table in the right table, those rows are skipped:

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM certificates AS c
INNER JOIN rel__staff_certificate AS sc ON sc.cert_id = c.cert_id
WHERE sc.staff_id = ?
ORDER BY c.cert_id
```

More on *joins* can be found in the documentation - basic [`JOIN`](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#join-clause) structure and [`JOIN` operators](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#join-operator).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with join:

```sql
SELECT cert_date
FROM certificates
JOIN rel__staff_certificate USING (cert_id)
WHERE staff_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a SQL join. Here's an example that gives the relevant information:

```sql
SELECT 
    staff.staff_id, 
    staff.name, 
    certificates.caption, 
    certificates.description, 
    rel__staff_certificate.cert_date, 
    rel__staff_certificate.comments
FROM rel__staff_certificate staff 
INNER JOIN certificates ON certificates.cert_id = rel__staff_certificate.cert_id 
INNER JOIN staff ON staff.staff_id = rel__staff_certificate.staff_id
WHERE staff.staff_id = ?
```

The `WHERE` statement may be optional if you want all staff members with all of their certs in one query.